# Comparing a String in Context with a regular String in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am using parsec to parse an input and I am storing the parsed characters to a function that is then called in a case expression where I compare the parsed string with a set of keywords.
This is the code I have for this:

```
import Text.Parsec.Prim
import Text.Parsec.Char
import Text.Parsec.Error
import Text.Parsec.String
import Text.Parsec.Combinator

tokenize :: Parser String
tokenize =do op <- many1 $ letter   <|> 
                           char '+' <|> 
                           char '^' <|> 
                           char '-' <|> 
                           char '>' <|> 
                           char '*' 
             return  op

curveOpt inval = case tokenize of
                      (Parser "++")   -> 
                        (do  c  <- curve
                             curveOpt $ Connect inval c)
```

The error I get from the compiler is:

```
 Couldn't match type `[Char]'
                  with `ParsecT String () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity String'
    Expected type: Parser String
      Actual type: [Char]
    In the pattern: "++"
    In a case alternative:
        "++"
          -> (do { c <- curve;
                   curveOpt $ Connect inval c })
    In the expression:
      case tokenize of {
        "++"
          -> (do { c <- curve;
                   curveOpt $ Connect inval c }) }
```

From what I understand is that I am trying to compare a Parser String with a String. How is it possible to compare these two different types?
Should I maybe change the type of tokenize, if yes how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which variant of parsec / Attoparsec are you importing?

Comment: check the question again. just added the imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tokenize` returns a string inside a Parser monad.
You would optimally want to pull it out in a do notation inside `curveOpt`:

```
curveOpt inval = do op <- tokenize
                    case op of
                      "++"   -> .....
```